How is this double switch wired up?
This is the back of a double switch.
It controls two lights:

entry way in the house
outdoor light w/ light sensor (next to front door)


It’s a 3 way switch, but we don’t have another switch that is being used with this one.
Why is the 3W connected? How are they lights connected.
I’m assuming one is line in and the the other two just go to the two lights.
Update
I called up the manufacturer and they said that the ‘A’ contacts are for one single pole switch.
COM A is where you connect to hot. SP A is for your first light.
If you connect the 3W B to your second load. That acts like a single pole switch.
COM B can be use as a the hit for a separate circuit if you remove the ‘spilt tab’.
You can use the all the ‘B’ contacts for a 3 Way application.


Pictures of the front and back of the switch and the wiring would help. 2. What exactly do you mean when you say that it controls two lights? Can you switch each light on and off separately, or can you only alternate between which one is on?


A 3-way switch with only one traveler connected is effectively an ordinary switch. My guess is that this regular + 3-way double switch is just what the installer had on hand at the time.
If it is working, leave it as is. If you want to replace with different switches, just consider the existing "3W B" wire as the switched hot (just like "SP A" for the top switch).
